# Reload UITableView when button clicked in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a button in my table view cell and I want to reload the whole view, which is a base controller.

This class is what I want to reload (refresh, recall the view controller maybe).

```
import UIKit 

class TableVC: BaseController, DBDelegate, PLDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewDB: UITableView!

}
```

And this is where I must do it:

```
import UIKit

class DailySpeakingLesson: UITableViewCell {

}
```

Comment: if your cell only have that action, you must do it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath UITableViewDelegate method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **delegate** for this.

Set the delegate for the custom cell in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, then call `tableViewDB.reloadData()` inside the delegate's function.

**TableVC**

```
class TableVC: BaseController, DBDelegate, PLDelegate, DailySpeakingLessonDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewDB: UITableView!

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let dailySpeakingLesson = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId") as! DailySpeakingLesson
        dailySpeakingLesson.delegate = self

        return dailySpeakingLesson
    }

    func dailySpeakingLessonButtonPressed() {
        tableViewDB.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**DailySpeakingLesson**

```
class DailySpeakingLesson: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: DailySpeakingLessonDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
        delegate?.dailySpeakingLessonButtonPressed()
    }
}
```

**Delegate**

```
protocol DailySpeakingLessonDelegate: class {
    func dailySpeakingLessonButtonPressed()
}
```

Comment: with a little bit change, it worked for me very well. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use delegate pattern. If you have a button in DemoTableViewCell which you are using in BaseTableViewController make a protocol BaseTableViewCellDelegate and assign delegate of BaseTableViewCell to BaseTableViewController so that base viewcontroller is notified button is pressed in the cell.

```
protocol DemoTableViewCell Delegate: class {
  func didTapDemoButton(onCell: DemoTableViewCell)
}

class DemoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  weak var delegate: DemoTableViewCellDelegate?

  @IBAction func demoButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didTapDemoButton(onCell: self)
  }
}

class BaseTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: DemoTableViewCell), for: indexPath)
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
  }

}

extension BaseTableViewController: DemoTableViewCellDelegate {
  func didTapDemoButton(onCell: DemoTableViewCell) {
    //Whenever the button in cell is pressed this delegate method gets called because we have set delegate of DemoTableViewCell as of the base view controller.
    //now you can do here whatever you want when button is pressed.

    tableView?.reloadData()
  }
}
```